# Prevent 'cd' remembering symbolic links traversed

Tags: bash, shell, directory, symbolic-link

Say you have directory ~/mytool that softlinks to /usr/local/mytool. Then `cd mytool` leaves your current directory as ~/mytool, which may cause scripts to behave incorrectly. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

With some googling, I see that you can achieve this as follows:

```
cd $1 ; cd `pwd -P`
```

Is there no switch to 'cd'? Environment variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you type `set -P` in bash all commands such as cd, pwd will follow the physical path. Else you can use `cd -P` and `pwd -P` for temporary changes to the default behavior.

From the manpage of bash:

```
          -P      If  set,  the shell does not follow symbolic links when executing commands such as cd that change the cur-
                  rent working directory.  It uses the physical directory structure instead.  By default, bash  follows  the
                  logical chain of directories when performing commands which change the current directory.
```

To make this permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc` file, for example.

Answer (score 4):

"cd" is a built in in most shells.  In bash, you can get the behavior you want by adding

```
set -P
```

in a startup script (.bashrc, say).

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu/Debian (not sure about BSD), `cd -P symlink` puts me in the resolved symlink path. (Same behavior as pwd -P)

Tested using:

```
mkdir a
ln -s a b
cd -P b && pwd
```

Comment: Yep that seems to work on RHEL (but not on MacOSX, which I was using before)